# Excel Multi-Dimensional Lookup - One Criteria (Row) & One Array (Column)

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have a data set. This data has unique IDs. These IDs are assigned to another data set with various columns. Depending on an array (which is subject to change), I need to be able to look up that ID in the second data set and return the text from a specific column.

For example, if in the first data set I have ID "24" I need a formula that will pick out "C" because it is in the array, but if C at some point in the future changes to I it will return "I". I have a really long IF-IFERROR-MATCH-INDEX... formula currently, but there has to be a better way. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Criteria #1:    24
Criteria #2 - Array:    A   H   C   J   E   F

22  A   G
23  B   H
24  C   I
25  D   J
26  E   K
27  F   L

Comment: is it possible that there can be one then 1 match of the array with the other columns and how many columns are there with letters

Comment: No the real array has crazy long text strings. it is impossible to have the same text value

Comment: The significance of Criteria #2 is that it determines which column the lookup find and returns. However, they change for each ID #. Therefore, I can't just do a vlookup(24,array[22:L],3,0).

Comment: I know it is ridiculous that I have to come up with a formula for this, but I didn't set it up this way and it is too much data to change now.

Comment: Since you have column letters vs. numbers, try creating a dynamic cell address using the Indirect function. Indirect allows you to constuct a cell address based on variables. It makes a great switch.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have column letters vs. numbers, try creating a dynamic cell address using the Indirect function. Indirect allows you to constuct a cell address based on variables. It makes a great switch.  For example, you can use:

```
=indirect("'Sheet1'!"&A1&3)
```

to get the value from sheet1!C3, assuming the value in cell A1 = "C"

Indirect functions allow you to use column letters in concatenating a cell address.